# output.filename is required

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

**System**

macOS Sierra, node v5.6.0, webpack v 2.2.1 - Was working fine in Webpack 1.8.0

**Work**

Converting JS to TS

**Current behavior**

This is the error message

```
Error: 'output.filename' is required, either in config file or as --output-filename
at processOptions (/Users/sagardubey/workspace/ts-sdk/node_modules/webpack/bin/convert-argv.js:488:11)
at processConfiguredOptions (/Users/sagardubey/workspace/ts-sdk/node_modules/webpack/bin/convert-argv.js:141:4)
at module.exports (/Users/sagardubey/workspace/ts-sdk/node_modules/webpack/bin/convert-argv.js:117:10)
at Object. (/Users/sagardubey/workspace/ts-sdk/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js:153:40)
at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
at startup (node.js:140:18)
```

This is my config file. There's no typo in filename or anywhere that I can see

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require('path')
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: {
    "ym.min": "./src/bootstrap.ts",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "ts-loader"
          },
          {
            loader: "tslint-loader",
            enforce: "pre"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    output: {
      filename: '[name].js',
      path: './dist'
    },
    plugins: [],
    resolve: {
      modules: [
        "node_modules",
        path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')
      ],
      extensions: [".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".js", "*"],
      enforceExtension: false,
      alias: {
        'handlebars': 'handlebars/runtime.js'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you try to use uglifyJS like so - it says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'unshift' of undefined"

```
var config = require('./webpack.config');
    var webpack = require('webpack');

    config.plugins.unshift(new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      },
      output: {
        comments: false,
      },
    }));

    module.exports = config;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't define `output.filename` but `module.output.filename` which doesn't exist. Same goes for `plugins` and `resolve` they should not be under `module` but at the top level. You need to close the curly brace for `module` after the `rules` array.

Another problem is that you try to set `enforce: "pre"` on a loader, but that is meant to go on a rule. So you need to have two rules for `.ts`, one rule that has `enforce: "pre"` for the `tslint-loader` and the other one with just the `ts-loader`.

Your config should be like this:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require('path')
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: {
    "ym.min": "./src/bootstrap.ts",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        enforce: "pre",
        use: [
          {
            loader: "tslint-loader"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "ts-loader"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }, // End of module
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: './dist'
  },
  plugins: [],
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      "node_modules",
      path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')
    ],
    extensions: [".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".js", "*"],
    enforceExtension: false,
    alias: {
      'handlebars': 'handlebars/runtime.js'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Michael . However, I'm still having trouble. When I use - 

/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.js

I get the following <this is cutoff> - 

Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.module.rules[0].use should be one of these:
   non-empty string | function | object { loader?, options?, query? } | function

Comment: The problem was `enforce` is not allowed on loaders, but required on rules. I updated the answer to fix that.

Comment: Ooh that wasn't clear at all from [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#module-preloaders-and-module-postloaders-was-removed)  - thanks so much @michael !

Comment: Tangential question - 

resolve: {
    modules: [
      "node_modules",
      path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')
    ],

The path.join is redundant here right? Not sure how I'm supposed to be using this.

Also, not sure about the alias stuff.

Comment: You're correct. In fact you can remove `modules` completely, because `node_modules` is the default. For details have a look at [resolve.modules](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-modules).

Answer (score 0):

I got this error, when I had by mistake two instances of module.exports in the webpack.config.js file, removing extra module.exports object fixed the issue

Also this issue comes in case you misspell correct(module.exports) to wrong(module.export)